# Kubuntu uses random minimize effects

Tags: kubuntu, kde, effects, minimize, kwin

I'm using Kubuntu 12.04 with KDE 4.10 however this issue is also present on my other machines running stock KDE from Kubuntu 12.04 and 12.10. I'm using the Nvidia currrent-updates driver.

The problem is the minimize effect seems to be rather random. Most of the times it will use the preferred and default way (which is the "Slide to taskbar, while decreasing the overall window size (a bit like windows 7))

But sometimes it will use a "Zoom out" effect which will make the window zoom out in the middle of the screen. Another way to describe this effect will be "The window is sucked into the desktop")

How do I make KDE only use the first mentioned effect ?

In KWin: desktop effects I have only enabled the option "Minimize effect" which has no configuration options. I haven't done any configuration changes of the desktop effects at all.

best regards :)

Comment: Have you been messing with the windows/effects settings?

Comment: As said in the question, no I haven't changed any effect settings :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have this bug:

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=242772

Please, read the comments 36, 38 and 39. There you have the temporary solution I found.

Regards.